# How to add label to UITableViewCells before inserting rows?

Tags: swift, uitableview

My goal is to insert a label that says "Loading..." to each visible UITableViewCell before I insert the rows into the tableview.

So far I have the following:
I have a fully functional table view that loads the correct number of cells as well as the information to go in each cell. The code is as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh", attributes: attributes)
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    MyChallengesTableView.addSubview(refreshControl) // not required when using UITableViewController

    self.BetCreatorUsernameArray.removeAll()
    self.BetDescriptionArray.removeAll()
    self.UserMoneyInBet.removeAll()
    self.BetTotalPoolArray.removeAll()
    self.BetEndDateArray.removeAll()

    loadData()

    self.MyChallengesTableView.reloadData()
}

//refresh table view action
@objc func refresh(refreshControl:UIRefreshControl) {
    // Code to refresh table view

    //refreshes tableview
    self.BetCreatorUsernameArray.removeAll()
    self.BetDescriptionArray.removeAll()
    self.UserMoneyInBet.removeAll()
    self.BetTotalPoolArray.removeAll()
    self.BetEndDateArray.removeAll()

    loadData()

    self.MyChallengesTableView.reloadData()

    //stops refreshing
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.BetDescriptionArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyChallengesCell", for: indexPath) as! MyChallengesTableViewCell

    cell.BetDescriptionOutlet.text = BetDescriptionArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.UserMoneyInBetOutlet.text = ("Money In: $" + UserMoneyInBet[indexPath.row])
    cell.TotalBetPoolOutlet.text = ("Pool: $" + BetTotalPoolArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.BetEndDateOutlet.text = ("End Date: " + BetEndDateArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.BetCreatorUsername = BetCreatorUsernameArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.betInformation = ["BetDescription" : BetDescriptionArray[indexPath.row],
                           "BetAmount" : UserMoneyInBet[indexPath.row],
                           "TotalMoneyInBet" : BetTotalPoolArray[indexPath.row],
                           "BetEndDate" : BetEndDateArray[indexPath.row],
                           "BetCreatorUsername" : BetCreatorUsernameArray[indexPath.row]]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(152)
}

@objc func loadData(){
    //get username of current user
    self.databaseRef.child("Users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("Username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        self.currentUserUsername = snapshot.value as! String

    //make dictionary for each bet that a user is in
        self.databaseRef.child("UserBets").child(self.currentUserUsername).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot1) in

            if snapshot1.exists(){

            let UserBetsDictionary = snapshot1.value as! NSDictionary
                for (Bet, _) in UserBetsDictionary {

    //get bet information from the bets in database
                    self.databaseRef.child("Bets").child((Bet as? String)!).child("BetInfo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot2) in

                        let BetInfoDictionary = snapshot2.value as! NSDictionary

                        self.BetCreatorUsernameArray.append((BetInfoDictionary["Creator Username"] as! String))
                        self.BetDescriptionArray.append((BetInfoDictionary["BetDescription"] as! String))
                        self.UserMoneyInBet.append((BetInfoDictionary["BetAmount"] as! String))
                        self.BetTotalPoolArray.append((BetInfoDictionary["TotalMoneyInBet"] as! String))
                        self.BetEndDateArray.append((BetInfoDictionary["BetEndTime"] as! String))

                        //insert the rows
                        if self.BetCreatorUsernameArray.count != 0 {
                            self.MyChallengesTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.BetCreatorUsernameArray.count-1, section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I'm not sure if the code matters too much at this point. In short, I want to add a label before running the function "loadData" in ViewDidAppear and then hide the label once the function is ran and the rows are inserted.

Comment: Rather than inserting/removing a label, it would probably be easier to have one always in the cell and change its "hidden" attribute.

Comment: @PhillipMills I tried this but can't seem to figure out how to get this to show before the rows are inserted.

Comment: Why do you name all your instances from capital letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will suit you, just make an extension like this:

```
extension UITableView {

  func startLoading() {
    let view = UIView()
    separatorStyle = .none
    let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
    activityIndicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.text = "Loading..."
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    self.backgroundView = view
  }

  func stopLoading() {
    clearTableView()
  }

  func clearTableView() {
    separatorStyle = .singleLine
    self.backgroundView = nil
  }

}
```

And after that just invoke method `startLoading` on your tableView instance before request, and on result from request invoke `stopLoading` method.

Comment: something is wrong with the function "startLoading()" which doesn't allow it to be called in viewdidappear. Is that how it should be used? In theory this extension looks like it will work otherwise.

Comment: do you invoke It like: self.MyChallengesTableView. startLoading()?

Comment: Now I only need to figure out how to add this subview to each cell before inserting the rows. Is this possible? Or is it only possible for the whole table view?

Comment: It is possible, you can use `tableView.visibleCells.forEach{ cell in }`, where in closure you can customise your views